# Pipeline will fail on GCP when writing tensorflow transform metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, tensorflow-transform

I hope somebody here can help. I've been googling this error like crazy but haven't found anything.

I have a pipeline that works perfectly when executed locally but it fails when executed on GCP. The following are the error messages that I get.

> Workflow failed. Causes: S03:Write transform
>   fn/WriteMetadata/ResolveBeamFutures/CreateSingleton/Read+Write
>   transform fn/WriteMetadata/ResolveBeamFutures/ResolveFutures/Do+Write
>   transform fn/WriteMetadata/WriteMetadata failed., A work item was
>   attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually
>   lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "preprocess.py", line 491,
>   in 
>       main()   File "preprocess.py", line 487, in main
>       transform_data(args,pipeline_options,runner)   File "preprocess.py", line 451, in transform_data
>       eval_data |= 'Identity eval' >> beam.ParDo(Identity())   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 335,
>   in **exit**
>       self.run().wait_until_finish()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py",
>   line 897, in wait_until_finish
>       (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self) apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException:
>   Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py",
>   line 582, in do_work
>       work_executor.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py",
>   line 166, in execute
>       op.start()   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 294, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>   (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10607)
>       def start(self):   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 295, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>   (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10501)
>       with self.scoped_start_state:   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 300, in
>   apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
>   (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:9702)
>       pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py",
>   line 225, in loads
>       return dill.loads(s)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in
>   loads
>       return load(file)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in
>   load
>       obj = pik.load()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
>       dispatchkey   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
>       obj = cls.**new**(cls, *args) TypeError: **new**() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Any ideas??

Thanks,

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pipeline works locally but fails on GCP it's possible that you're running into a version mismatch.

What TF, tf.Transform, beam versions are you running locally and on GCP?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Zohar!  For future reference, This was solved by adding REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow==1.4.0','tensorflow-transform==0.3.0', 'apache_beam==2.1.1'] via setuptools